# Compare the count of positive to negative events

Tags: r

I have data for the count of positive, negative, and neutral events.
For example: 8 (positive), 5 (negative), and 1 (neutral).

I wish to find some way to calculate the confidence interval for the ratio 8/5.

Another example is :6 (positive), 0 (negative), and 2 (neutral).

Here is an example of the data:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be great if you can provide a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your data!

Comment: I added some example data - please use the link "enter image description here"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A start would be to use `table(sign(vec))`, though it has a flaw:

```r
set.seed(42)
vec <- runif(30, -1, 1)
vec
#  [1]  0.82961209  0.87415083 -0.42772093  0.66089525  0.28349104  0.03819190
#  [7]  0.47317663 -0.73066681  0.31398458  0.41012957 -0.08451645  0.43822450
# [13]  0.86934449 -0.48914235 -0.07541435  0.88002905  0.95645286 -0.76502528
# [19] -0.05000584  0.12066549  0.80806277 -0.72257966  0.97778346  0.89333647
# [25] -0.83512488  0.02842357 -0.21959307  0.81147626 -0.10606074  0.67200852
table(sign(vec))
# -1  1 
# 11 19
```

The flaw is common with `table`: if it does not see it, it won't report `0` for it (and it is not a flaw in `table`, just our use of and expectation from it). We can fix this without much difficulty:

```r
table(c(sign(vec), -1:1)) - 1L
# -1  0  1 
# 11  0 19
```

The `-1:1` appends one of each of our expected values into the results from `sign`, and the `- 1L` afterwards removes the counts we introduced.

It might be easy to assume that you will always have at least one of each of `-1`, `0`, and `1` (though your sample data clearly shows having a `0`) ... I suggest that it is rarely perfect, and adding this fail-safe adds very little overhead while providing assurance of completeness.

On a similar note, if you suspect you may see `NA` at any point, then you can add `useNA="always"`, but the `- 1L` becomes problematic. For that, we need to include `NA` in our inserted data using the same technique:

```r
table(c(sign(vec), c(-1:1, NA)), useNA='always') - 1L
#   -1    0    1 <NA> 
#   11    0   19    0 

table(c(sign(c(NA, vec)), c(-1:1, NA)), useNA='always') - 1L
#   -1    0    1 <NA> 
#   11    0   19    1
```